# Nexus 5 with cracked screen - Screen is always off when in a call

Tags: nexus-5, phone-app, proximity-sensor

I cracked the screen of my LG Nexus 5 (running Android Lollipop 5.0.1). This seems to have made the proximity sensor go haywire. Now, whenever I make a call, the screen immediately goes black and stays that way. Hitting the power button makes it come back for a fraction of a second sometimes but not reliably.

I've enabled 'power button ends call' just to have the option of ending a call, but calling automated services to top up my phone credit or pay a bill is impossible since I have to use the on-screen keypad to which I have no access.

I have used the ProximityScreenOff-Lite app before upgrading to Lollipop and it was working. After the upgrade, however, no matter what settings I use it doesn't work any more. Is there a way to force the screen to stay on during a call in stock Android 5.0.1? Are there any other apps to try? Anything to just completely disable the proximity sensor since its useless as it is anyway?

Comment: Just so you don't think you're crazy, I have this exact issue.  Cracked screen, can't use Google Hangouts for calls because the screen immediately goes black.  Sometimes cleaning the glass over the sensors at the phone helps for a call or two.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133160/screen-turns-off-during-call-due-to-problem-with-proximity-sensor-xperia-z3-co

Answer (score 1):

[Proximity Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vrognaas.proximityfix) app helped me on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and in the reviews, fixed it for Nexus 4 as well. Maybe it is worth a try?

EDIT: [Disable Proximity Sensor AOSP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2436999) thread may give a pointer on disabling proximity sensor by echo command.

Comment: Sure! Keep up the good work. :)

Comment: Proximity Fix app doesn't exist anymore...