# Disable android Sensor only for Call

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, sensors, call-screening

I'm using device GT i 9082, Android 6 AOSP ROM. My phone has a problem. While answering/dialing call, putting phone near to ear the screen goes off - this works fine but when taking phone off the ear the screen doesn't come up.

I was wondering if I can stop that functionality of sensor only for call? or any other solution please.

Comment: Possible with automation tools like MacroDroid

Comment: Also see for possible solutions http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92267/nexus-5-with-cracked-screen-screen-is-always-off-when-in-a-call/127462?s=1|0.4173#127462

Comment: Simple workaround is to press the power button twice. This will turn on your screen, but you'll have to unlock your phone again. Less than ideal.

Comment: Is there a phone case or screen protector obstructing the proximity sensor? It doesn't even need to be total.

Comment: @ethanz yes, there's...

Comment: @Akkitech There's your problem. It's a screen protector I'm guessing?

Comment: The problem may be caused by some obstacle (screen guard or flip cover). Or your proximity sensor needs some fix. In that case try to refer this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2436999