# Disable proximity sensor on Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, proximity-sensor

My Nexus 5's proximity sensor is broken and I verified the same using the [Proximity Sensor Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_borekbandell.Proximity_sensor_test).

As usual, the screen goes black during the calls and I use the power button to end the call. But the problem is during whatsapp or skype call, power button doesn't help and I need to search for a Bluetooth or ear phones to dial or receive a call.

Kindly help me to disable proximity sensor or any other work arounds

Edit: Unfortunately I am not interested in rooting. So I am looking for some kind of app.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133160/screen-turns-off-during-call-due-to-problem-with-proximity-sensor-xperia-z3-co and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982571/disable-proximity-sensor-during-call

Comment: My Nexus5 has the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MaxB There is no one good app. In fact, I got new phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, it seems the proximity sensor doesn't work properly and it always see there is something near the phone. During the phone call, this will automatically turn off the screen.

I work around this using the app named "Proximity Screen Off Lite" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itsme4ucz.screenoff

I configure the app as below.

1. Screen On/Off Modes
   Check "Cover and hold to turn on Screen"
   Timeout: 1 second
   Check "Disable Accidentla Lock"
   Timeout: 4 seconds
2. All settings 
   Check "Disable in Lanscape"
   Check "Lock phone on screen ON"
3. [Advanced] Configure Sensore
   Select sensor: Proximity sensor
   Value when sensor covered: 0
   Value when sensor un-covered: 1

Turn on the service and enjoy your phone calls.

Or

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiledirection.proximitysensorreset

This may help too

Hope it help.

Comment: requires rooted phone?