# How can I configure Android's default phone calling application do that the screen doesn't turn off automatically after ca. 20 seconds during a call?

Tags: calls

When I make a phone call using the speaker, the screen turns off after about 20 seconds after the call started.

How can I configure Android's default phone calling application do that the screen doesn't turn off automatically after about 20 seconds during a call?

I use the default Android phone call application on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: @beeshyams been able to use the numpad, mute/unmute, enable or disable the speaker, see phone notifications etc while I'm in a call

Comment: Which means you want to turn off the proximity sensor while on call //[automation solutions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133160/131553) are one option to try//please add the explanation to the question. Comments may be deleted// be aware that those solutions may not work on all devices /OSes plus the automation options may have changed.

Comment: @beeshyams thanks no actually the issue is not the proximity sensor. Even though triggering the sensor, When I make a phone call using the speaker, the screen turns off after about 20 seconds after the call started.

Comment: @beeshyams thanks I am not placing the phone near my ear but instead using speakers or Bluetooth headphones